# Two network interfaces assigned to addresses from two DHCP servers

Tags: networking, dhcp

If we have an Ubuntu box with two network interfaces (NIF1/2) connected with two other DHCP server boxes (DHCP1/2) below,

DHCP1 192.168.1.1/24 <---> NIF1
DHCP2 192.168.2.1/24 <---> NIF2

so we need NIF1 be assigned to the address from DHCP1 and NIF2 from DHCP2 accordingly, how can we configure the Ubuntu box?

### @EDIT

If [network-manager](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NetworkManager) is not installed yet, we can also enable dhcp on the interfaces [manually](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NetworkConfigurationCommandLine/Automatic).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the installer did not create a connection profile for each network interface automatically during system installation, you can go to **Edit connections** and create them yourself.

Make sure that:

1. On the first tab, the option to **connect automatically if available** is checked for both interfaces.
2. Each profile is linked to the respective interface's **MAC address** so that you don't end up with two profiles linked to the same one.  The addresses are provided by the network manager automatically.

All other settings are configured by network manager automatically to acquire the necessary data from DHCP.